# Accessing plug-in info in lightroom sdk plug-in

Tags: plugins, lua, adobe, lightroom

I would like to access the VERSION field (returned in Info.lua) from other code in my plug-in. I could find no documentation as to where the information returned from Info.lua is stored. Is there a way to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an official way, but since it is simply yet another lua file returning a table and it is located inside the plugin path, you can simply import it:

```
local Info = require 'Info.lua'
```

Inside my plugin, I'm using Info.VERSION.revision and passing it to all the backend requests, so that the server knows what plugin version is used.